# WPA Enterprise with Azure ADDS for Aruba IAP

Tags: azure-active-directory, ldap, ntlm, freeradius, aruba

I wanted to use my Aruba IAP with my Azure ADDS, so secureLDAP is enabled.
In the beginning, I tried to use the LDAP configuration directly on Aruba, which didn't work, and I have no access to any logs and don't know why. (but this LDAP works with openvpn, so LDAP is fine).

So I build a freeradius server in AWS and used [this](https://www.nasirhafeez.com/freeradius-with-ldaps-on-azure-ad-domain-services/) manual for connecting LDAP with freeRadius.
But then, the radtest works fine, but it doesn't work with WPA2 Enterprise from Windows.
I received the error:

```
(187) ldap: WARNING: No "known good" password added. Ensure the admin user has permission to read the password attribute
(187) ldap: WARNING: PAP authentication will *NOT* work with Active Directory (if that is what you were trying to configure)
(187) mschap: WARNING: No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create NT-Password
(187) mschap: Client is using MS-CHAPv1 with NT-Password
(187) mschap: ERROR: FAILED: No NT-Password.  Cannot perform authentication
(187) mschap: ERROR: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
```

The manual is for PAP.
Now I am searching for a solution for connection FreeRadius with Azure ADDS (secureLDAP) with MS-CHAP2. It supposed to be ntlm_auth.

Now I am lost, cuz Idk how I can set up this.
Maybe anyone has also another idea to solve my task.

Comment: Hello @Salihzett, this might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-ldaps .

Comment: no it doesnt. LDAP is working, this is not the problem. Meanwhile I found one git freeradius-oauth2 which could also resolve my todo. This is in progress now. Thanks anyway.